# npm including same dependency twice with different versions

Tags: javascript, npm, versioning

Is it possible in package.json to include the same dependency twice, but with different versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "projectX-v1.0.0": "ssh://git@github.com/xxx/projectX.git#v1.0.0",
    "projectX-v1.0.1": "ssh://git@github.com/xxx/projectX.git#v1.0.1"
}
```

The best I could come up with is to change the name (see above) of the included `projectX` to `projectX-v1.0.0` and `projectX-v1.0.1` in its releases/tags and package.json in order to end up with two separate folders in `node_modules` folder.

The reason why I need this is the following omni-repository structure:

```
/omni/
/omni/frontend
/omni/frontend/projectA
/omni/frontend/projectB
...
/omni/package.json
```

`projectA` would use `projectX-v1.0.0` and `projectB`  would use `projectX-v1.0.1` (bundling with browserify)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with vanilla npm, although the community has [talked about](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499) it extensively. That said, Scott Hardy's [npm-install-version](https://github.com/scott113341/npm-install-version) package will let you install node modules to versioned, or custom, directories.

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad that there is no elegant way for this. Even the npm-install-version boils down to the ugly idea I had of somehow creating two different folders in node_modules.

We went along with the method described in the question, each major version is a branch on the repo, i.e. "v1", "v2" branches and name within package.json is different on each branch, i.e. "project-v1" and project-v2" respectively. I think that strategy can work out for our case, since we are in control of the consumed project. However for external offical dependencies, we will consider npm-install-version.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm not sure what ramifications it would have for your case in particular, but you might also consider defining package.json at the project level rather than having one singular package.json at the root of your repository.

Comment: I've considered that too and it would work for other projects. However in my particular case it wouldn't, since there are a lot of common dependencies (mostly devDependencies) across the projects that yield around 700MB node_modules folder, 90% of which are common with respect to disk size. Duplicating those would waste a lot of space and time when doing npm install, since there is no package.json inheritance to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for describing why that wouldn't work for your setup. I think that'll be helpful for anyone who stumbles onto your question via search and is trying to weigh and the pros and cons of each possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

NPM has said that they don't plan to implement this feature, but I've found a way around it. I forked the package repository on github and renamed it. Then I installed this new repo as a dependency in my project using:

```
npm i -S git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:<org>/<renamed-project>.git
```

Now, I can upgrade the actual npm package and change all of the references to it in my project to the new, renamed-project git repo dependency. It's a lot of extra work, but I found it easier than switching to yarn or another package manager with package aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias:

`npm i <package_alias>@npm:<package_name>@<version>`

Eg

`npm i capacitor-core-v2@npm:@capacitor/core@"^2.0.0"`

will add to your dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "capacitor-core-v2": "npm:@capacitor/core@^2.5.0",
}
```

References:

- [How to Install Multiple Versions of the Same Package in NPM](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package-in-npm-71c29b12e253)